# Private access on Apache Math

Tags: android, apache, math, syntax-error

I am using Apache Common Path jar library on Android for my aplication, I need to use from Apache on special package Erf class.

So after add my library on my project, exactly with erf class I get an error, the sentence is easy:

```
Erf example = new Erf();
```

Error:

> Erf() has private access on 'org.apache.commons.math3.special.Erf'

If anybody can help me... Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ERF](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Erf.html) is a static helper utility class, so you dont instantiate it and instead usage would be something like:

```
double x = 10.10;
double someValue = Erf.erf(x)
```